# Initialize and feed array data from sql in Java

Tags: java, sql, arrays, initialization

I am working on myTable class in Java that would map data in SQL to usable arrays for further processing. I noticed that in order to initialize and feed array I need to run 2 queries. Is there any simpler solution?

Currently I have something like:

```
   float[] data;

   msql.query("select count(*) from `%s`", tableName);
   msql.next();
   size = msql.getInt(1); // get size of array 
   data = new float[size];
```

and then I have to run second query:

```
   int row = 0;
   msql.query("SELECT * FROM `%s`", tableName); 
   while (msql.next()) { 
   data[row] = msql.getFloat(2);
   row++;
   }
```

Is it possible to get the size of an array somehow automatically without running 1st query?
or to expand it as data is loading ?

I know about arrayLists but I prefer to use arrays as they are quicker.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you use an ArrayList when your building the data, then clone the arrayList to an array for further downstream processing.

```
List<Float> dataList = new ArrayList<Float>();
   msql.query("SELECT * FROM `%s`", tableName); 
   while (msql.next()) { 
   dataList.add(msql.getFloat(2));
   row++;
   }

// copy list to array
float [] data = dataList.toArray(new float[dataList.size()]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to initialize data as Float[] not float[] (as in your code) and it worked. However I did some tests and solution with arrayList + 1 SQL query is slower than method with arrays + 2 SQL queries. Secondly I tried expand() method for arrays as in [link](http://processing.org/reference/expand_.html) but it is slower than 2SQLs as well! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of some kind that can be dynamically resized as required.

Check out [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size of an array once it's made, this is why `List` or `ArrayList` is preferred for what you want to do.